# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExceptionfieldIndex on a Row without schema is undefined: Exception on row.getAs[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code is throwing an Exception Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: fieldIndex on a Row without schema is undefined. This is happening when a on a dataframe that has been returned after a groupByKey and flatMap invocation on a dataframe using ExpressionEncoder, groupedByKey and a flatMap is invoked.

Logical flow:
originalDf->groupByKey->flatMap->groupByKey->flatMap->show

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ IntegerType, StructField, StructType}

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer



  object Test {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      val values = List(List("1", "One") ,List("1", "Two") ,List("2", "Three"),List("2","4")).map(x =>(x(0), x(1)))
      val session = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate
      import session.implicits._
      val dataFrame = values.toDF


      dataFrame.show()
      dataFrame.printSchema()

      val newSchema = StructType(dataFrame.schema.fields
        ++ Array(
        StructField("Count", IntegerType, false)
      )
      )

      val expr = RowEncoder.apply(newSchema)

      val tranform =  dataFrame.groupByKey(row => row.getAs[String]("_1")).flatMapGroups((key, inputItr) => {
        val inputSeq = inputItr.toSeq

        val length = inputSeq.size
        var listBuff = new ListBuffer[Row]()
        var counter : Int= 0
        for(i <- 0 until(length))
        {
          counter+=1

        }

        for(i <- 0 until length ) {
          var x = inputSeq(i)
          listBuff += Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq ++ Array[Int](counter))
        }
        listBuff.iterator
      })(expr)

      tranform.show

      val newSchema1 = StructType(tranform.schema.fields
        ++ Array(
        StructField("Count1", IntegerType, false)
      )
      )
      val expr1 = RowEncoder.apply(newSchema1)
      val tranform2 =  tranform.groupByKey(row => row.getAs[String]("_1")).flatMapGroups((key, inputItr) => {
        val inputSeq = inputItr.toSeq

        val length = inputSeq.size
        var listBuff = new ListBuffer[Row]()
        var counter : Int= 0
        for(i <- 0 until(length))
        {
          counter+=1

        }

        for(i <- 0 until length ) {
          var x = inputSeq(i)
          listBuff += Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq ++ Array[Int](counter))
        }
        listBuff.iterator
      })(expr1)

      tranform2.show
    }
}
```

Following is the stacktrace

```
18/11/21 19:39:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 144.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 400, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: fieldIndex on a Row without schema is undefined.
at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.fieldIndex(Row.scala:342)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.fieldIndex(rows.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAs(Row.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getAs(rows.scala:166)
at com.quantuting.sparkutils.main.Test$$anonfun$4.apply(Test.scala:59)
at com.quantuting.sparkutils.main.Test$$anonfun$4.apply(Test.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AppendColumnsWithObjectExec$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(objects.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AppendColumnsWithObjectExec$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(objects.scala:298)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:149)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How to fix this code?

Comment: @user6910411: added the stacktrace. Will be difficult to put the reproducible code, as the flow is integrated in a framework over multiple libraries. But can answer whatever details would be required

Comment: Can you post the case class definitions for the two datasets? Did you add the naturalRank field to the second?

Comment: Also you can just do row => row.ticker if the schema is specified correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reported problem could be avoided by replacing the `fieldname` version of [getAs[T]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@getAs[T](fieldName:String):T) method (used in the function for `groupByKey`):

```
groupByKey(row => row.getAs[String]("_1"))
```

with the `field-position` version:

```
groupByKey(row => row.getAs[String](fieldIndexMap("_1")))
```

where `fieldIndexMap` maps field names to their corresponding field indexes:

```
val fieldIndexMap = tranform.schema.fieldNames.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

As a side note, your function for [flatMapGroups](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset@flatMapGroups[U](f:(K,Iterator[V])=%3ETraversableOnce[U])(implicitevidence$3:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) can be simplified into something like below:

```
val tranform2 = tranform.groupByKey(_.getAs[String](fieldIndexMap("_1"))).
  flatMapGroups((key, inputItr) => {
    val inputSeq = inputItr.toSeq
    val length = inputSeq.size
    inputSeq.map(r => Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ length))
  })(expr1)
```

The inconsistent behavior between applying the original `groupByKey/flatMapGroups` methods to "dataFrame" versus "tranform" is apparently related to how the methods handle a `DataFrame` versus a `Dataset[Row]`.

Comment: Accepting the answer after the expanded illustration. Also I have already raised a Spark bug yesterday https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26436

Answer (score 3):

Solution as received from JIRA on Spark project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26436

This issue is caused by how you create the row:

```
listBuff += Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq ++ Array[Int](counter))
```

Row.fromSeq creates a GenericRow and GenericRow's fieldIndex is not implemented because GenericRow doesn't have schema.

Changing the line to create GenericRowWithSchema can solve it:

```
listBuff += new GenericRowWithSchema((x.toSeq ++ Array[Int](counter)).toArray, newSchema)
```